# Counter Example on Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains

I have a question on find a counter example of Markov Chain. The question states as follows:

Suppose $X_0$, $X_1$ are the Markov chain whose state space is $\mathbb{Z}$, Since we know from Markov property, we know that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n | X_1 = i_0, X_2 = i_1, ... X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n | X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})
$$
now we want to find an example such that the following property doesn't holds:

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n \geq 0 | X_1 \geq 0, X_2 \geq 0, ... X_{n-1} \geq 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_n \geq 0 | X_{n-1} \geq0)
$$

My thought is to start from a state space with only three states $1$, $2$ and $3$, and the equality holds when $X_2$ is not depends on $X_1$ and $X_2$ so the inequality will holds. But I don't think my example is good enough. Can you guys come up with a better one? Thanks!

Comment: A Markov chain involves transition probabilities that depend on state alone.  I don't understand what precise example you have in mind, largely because you have said nothing about the transition probabilities.

Comment: If the state space $S$ is a subset of the nonnegative integers (such as your example $S=\{1, 2,3\}$), then the information $X_i\geq 0$ in fact provides no information ("we already know $X_i\geq 0$").  So your state space should include at least one negative integer.  I like the idea of using 3 states.

Comment: @hardmath I think we need to find a example such that the in which is transition probability fails in this equality